# Оптимизация DISTINCT в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вида:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE history_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE history (
    id    INT8 DEFAULT nextval('history_id_seq') NOT NULL CONSTRAINT history_key PRIMARY KEY,
    objid TEXT NOT NULL,
    descr TEXT,
    value FLOAT4,
    time  TIMESTAMP
);
ALTER TABLE public.history OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE INDEX idx_history_objid ON history USING BTREE (objid);
CREATE INDEX idx_history_time  ON history USING BTREE (time);

INSERT INTO history ( objid, descr, value, time ) VALUES
    ( 'a', 'a_descr1', 0, '2016-06-23 00:00:00' ),
    ( 'b', 'b_descr1', 1, '2016-06-23 00:00:01' ),
    ( 'c', 'c_descr1', 2, '2016-06-23 00:00:02' ),
    ( 'a', 'a_descr2', 3, '2016-06-23 00:00:03' );
```

Нужно выбрать уникальные идентификаторы(objid) и **последние** внесённые описания(descr), т.к. описания могут изменяться со временем.

```
    objid | descr
   -------+----------
      a   |  a_descr2
      b   |  b_descr1
      c   |  c_descr1
```

Необходимые мне функционал даёт запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (objid) objid, descr, time FROM history ORDER BY objid, time DESC;
```

Но на миллионах записей это очень длительный процесс. Просто выбрать уникальные objid быстро получилось с помощью рекурсивной функции:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE t(i) AS (
   SELECT min(objid) FROM history 
   UNION
   SELECT( SELECT objid FROM history
             WHERE objid > i
             ORDER BY objid
             LIMIT 1
         ) FROM t WHERE i is not null
 )
 SELECT * FROM t;
```

, но как взять описания непонятно. Буду благодарен любой идее.

Comment: Сколько в среднем уникальных `objid` из всего  набора? в процентном отношении

Comment: На практике их будет минимальное, почти постоянное количество стремящееся к 0%( в текущем состоянии 300 на 60млн, каждый день + 4млн )

Comment: А вариант завести таблицу справочник вообще не рассматривается? Еще можно попробовать отдельно получить уникальный набор, а потом выбрать описани для уникального набора по индексу отдельными подзапросами.

Comment: Была идея справочника составлюящегося с помощью триггеров на таблицах, но упадёт скорость записи, что критично. Второй предложенный вариант как раз и реализован( благо выполняться он будет достаточно редко ) , забыл об этом написать, но хотелось как-то покрасивее решение.

Comment: Навскидку, на больших объемах такой запрос: `SELECT h1.objId, h1.descr FROM history AS h1 JOIN (SELECT objid, MAX(time) AS time FROM history GROUP BY objId) AS h2 ON h2.objId = h1.objId AND h2.time = h1.time ORDER BY h1.objId, h1.time DESC` отрабатывает раза в 3-4 быстрее Вашего исходного. Но все равно долго, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * from history h 
  join (SELECT objid, max(time) as _time FROM tab 
        GROUP BY objid) t 
    on h.objid = t.objid and h.time = t._time
ORDER BY h.objid;
```

**UPD** Вообще, конечно эта история не предназначена для постоянного получения снэпшота, как основной рабочей таблицы, учитывая такие общие объемы по сравнению с изменениями. История предназначена чтоб смотреть изменения по каждому объекту или изменения за какой-то краткий промежуток времени, типа последние за час...

Comment: Вы верно заметили про историю - снэпшот изредка будет нужен для уточнения списка и последующего его сохранения отдельно в ФС. Ваш пример дал приемлемые результаты на тестовой базе в 2млн строк при 10 уникальных, позже проверю на чём-нибудь большем. Спасибо.